# scipy.optimize.curve_fit: Default value of max_nfev broken?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am experiencing unexpected behavior when calling [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) with the `max_nfev` argument. The documentation states that extra `kwargs` are passed on to [`leastsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) for `method='lm'` and to [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) otherwise. Also, `method` should default to `'trf'` (i.e. not `'lm'`) if `bounds` are provided. Finally, `least_squares` takes the `max_nfev` argument, which defaults to `100*len(x)` if not provided (or explicitly passed as `max_nfev=None`), `x` being one of the arrays on which to do the curve fitting.

I have a dataset (and matching function) on which [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) fails. The time it takes before the routine gives up depends linearly on `max_nfev`, as expected. However, this time is vastly different between specifying `max_nfev=100*len(x)` in the call to [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and not passing in `max_nfev` at all, which seems to go against the documented behavior.

Here is a script which demonstrates this:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

x, y = np.loadtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)

# Attempt curve fit
initial_guess = (1, 0)
bounds = ([-np.inf, 0], [np.inf, 15])
for max_nfev in (None, 1*len(x), 10*len(x), 100*len(x)):
    print('\nRunning with max_nfev = {}:'.format(max_nfev))
    t0 = time.time()
    try:
        scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
            lambda x, factor, exponent: factor*x**exponent,
            x,
            y,
            initial_guess,
            bounds=bounds,
            ftol=1e-10,
            maxfev=max_nfev,
        )
        deltat = time.time() - t0
        print('Succeeded after', deltat, 's')
    except RuntimeError:
        deltat = time.time() - t0
        print('Failed after', deltat, 's')
```

The script needs the dataset in `data.txt` (24 KB), which you can download [here](http://users-phys.au.dk/jmd/data.txt).

On my system, the output of this script is

> Running with max_nfev = None:
>   Failed after 0.10752344131469727 s
>
> Running with max_nfev = 441:
>   Failed after 0.17525863647460938 s
>
> Running with max_nfev = 4410:
>   Failed after 1.732572078704834 s
>
> Running with max_nfev = 44100:
>   Failed after 17.796284437179565 s

I would expect the first (`max_nfev=None`) and last (`max_nfev=100*len(x)`) call to take roughly the same amount of time to fail. To add to the mystery, it seems that instead of passing `max_nfev` I might just as well pass `maxfev`, which is not a valid argument of [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html), but instead the `maxfev`-equivalent argument taken by [`leastsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html).

Have I misunderstood something, or is the documentation or the implementation wrong?

I am experiencing this under both {SciPy 1.1.0, Python 3.6.5} and {SciPy 1.2.0, Python 3.7.1}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would expect the first (max_nfev=None) and last (max_nfev=100*len(x)) call to take roughly the same amount of time

Set a breakpoint at line 250 of scipy.optimize._lsq.trf.py:

```
    if max_nfev is None:
        max_nfev = x0.size * 100
```

At this point `x0` has just two elements, so your call that passed in `None` could equivalently have passed in 200. `x0` came from `p0`, which defaulted to `[1 0]`.

Based on this, your observed timings *do* make sense.

Comment: Aha, the `n` in the `least_squares` documentation refers to the number of variables! It has nothing to do with the size of the data.